# Efficient way to check if large number is divisible by 3

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

If

M<sub>p</sub>=2<sup>p</sup>-1 is prime ⇒

⇒ 2<sup>p</sup>-2⋮6 or 2<sup>p</sup>⋮6 ⇒

⇒ 2<sup>p-1</sup>-1⋮3 or 2<sup>p-1</sup>⋮3 ⇒

⇒ 2<sup>n</sup>-1⋮3 or 2<sup>n</sup>⋮3, n=p-1

In order to pick huge values for p to test if M<sub>p</sub> is a prime number, I believe this is a good preliminary test before going with the computationally expensive Lucas-Lehmer test.

But what is the fastest, most efficient way to test if two numbers, 2<sup>n</sup>-1 and 2<sup>n</sup>, are divisible by 3.

Other info that we can use from this is that n always ends in 0, 2, 6 or 8 (because p=n+1 is a prime). Maybe it helps in some way.

Thank you!

Comment: You are using a sledge hammer to crack a nut. If all you want to do is check divisibility by $3$, do your computations modulo $3$. The outcome is that $2^n$ is never divisible by $3$ because the sequence $2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4,2^5,2^6,…$ is equal modulo $3$ to $2,1,2,1,2,1,…$

Answer (score 1):

$2^n$ doesn't have the least chance to be divisible by $3$. As for $2^p-2$, you can compute modulo $3$:
$$2^p-2\equiv(-1)^p+1=0\mod 3$$
Thus a Mersenne prime has the form $6k+1$.

(you didn't mention it, but I suppose you're looking at Mersenne numbers, which require $p$ to be prime to have a chance to be prime too. I supposed $p$ is an odd prime).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I was talking about Mersenne numbers, thus the M<sub>p</sub> notation and the mention of Lucas-Lehmer algorithm(which can only be applied to Mersenne numbers). So should I understand that computing the modulo 3 is the most efficient way to check if 2<sup>n</sup>-1 is divisible by 3?

Comment: Yes. It simply uses $2\equiv -1\mod 3$. Do you know anything simpler?

Comment: Indeed, I do not know anything simpler. I was just thinking that there may be some kind of shortcut taking into account the circumstances. In the same way that there are algorithms to check if a number is prime, but the Lucas-Lehmer beats all of them by a large margin when it comes to Mersenne numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$2^n$ is *never* divisible by 3, by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

$2^n - 1$ is divisible by 3 iff $n$ is even, by Fermat's Little theorem / [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

The problem is that n is always even in the above case(see last line).